# Mean of a Non-Uniform Sample Rate

Tags: sampling, mean, resampling

I have a nonuniform sample rate. I want to take the mean of samples for a given interval, say an hour. Within the samples of this hour, I want to weight each time slice equally.

For example: if I have 100 samples in the first 10 minutes and 10 samples in the remaining 50 minutes, I don't want to overweight the first 10 minutes.

I'm looking for general information about this sort of mean and algorithms to perform this sort of mean on a stream of data.

Comment: May we presume the variations in the sampling rate are independent of the values of the samples?

Comment: Yes, you can presume that is the case.